# SQL Server Difference in dates Query AND TRIM

Tags: sql-server, date, trim

I've got a very tricky scenario below, if anyone can help i'd appreciate it a lot.

I have two tables:

TX

TX_External

TX has two columns: ID & Date_Reported

TX_External has two columns: ID & Date_Received

Essentially I want to find the difference in days between Date_Received from TX_external and Date_Reported from TX table. It has to be WORKING DAYS ONLY (no weekend or bank holidays).

So my final output should look like this

Customer ID  |  Days_Taken

MAIN PROBLEM. 
My main issue is that the id's in both tables are different ever so slightly, for example:

Tx- ID= AB_123456_ABC

TX_External- ID= AB_123456

So as you can see they are similar and refer to the same transaction but the TX table ID has random extras attached after the number in the version of "_ABC" and this could be extra numbers letters brackets etc. (so AB_123456_ABC, AB_123456_E (1), AB_123456_H, etc). To add to the confusion, the ID is not one consistent size ie they are all not AB_123456 as some could be AB_12345678! **So trim to the second _ and trim**

How do I trim that so I can get it exactly the same as the Tx_External ID (AB_123456) and then this will let me do a match so for that exact ID i can calculate the working day taken? Can I do this all in one query?

Sorry about massive description in advance, more than happy to explain further.

Comment: You could use the LEFT function. In this case Tx- ID = LEFT (TX_External- ID, 9)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but please see my edit change as the id's are not all one size

Comment: Looks like you want to trim each one to the second underscore and then join right?

Comment: Fix your database model and add bona fide foreign keys. As it is, you're going to have more and more problems in the future. You are asking for them.

Comment: @DanielMarcus yes that is exactly what i want

Comment: What's the database? Answers vary greatly depending on which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   select * from tx a 
        cross apply (select case when a.ID like '%[_]%[_]%' then
       replace(a.ID, reverse(left(reverse(a.ID), charindex('_', reverse(a.ID)))), '')
        else a.ID end txstripped)b
   join TX_External c cross apply (select case when c.ID like '%[_]%[_]%' then
     replace(c.ID, reverse(left(reverse(c.ID), charindex('_', reverse(c.ID)))), '')
     else ID end txexternal_stripped)d
   on b.txstripped=d.txexternal_stripped
```

Comment: This works for the relationship. The other requirement is to compute "business day difference", excluding weekends and bank holidays. It seems to me the database lacks information about holidays, so I don't see a way of doing this extra step.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. What do you mean @TheImpaler, how can i use the above query from daniel and find difference in Date_Reported minus Date_Received.

Comment: @TarikulIslam, Please try above updated answer - Just tested on my end and it works

Comment: Thank you so  much @DanielMarcus

Comment: @DanielMarcus do you know if it is possible to then work out the difference in dates in this one query

Comment: yes use datediff(day, 1stdatereportedvalue, 2nddatereportedvalue)

Comment: @DanielMarcus this works for normal days thank you. What if I wanted only working days (so no weekends or holidays ie xmas day)

Comment: To exclude weekend, add a where clause like this: ' ...where datepart(DW, datevalue) not in (1,7)'  For holidays you'll have to be more explicit by excluding the specific date or excluding something like the fourth thursday in november for thanksgiving etc